# How to say subject–verb–object (SVO) in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I want to make some notes on the general grammar of Chinese, and standard Chinese uses SVO or subject-verb-object. How do I say this in Chinese?

Google translate gives:

> 主语动词宾语

But other sites mention otherwise:

> 主动宾

Comment: Note, it is called 主词(subject)动词(verb)受詞(object) in Taiwan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is commonly called `主谓宾` (short for `主语，谓语，宾语`), where `主` is the subject, `谓` is the action/verb by the subject and `宾` is the object that is acted upon.

For example, in this sentence - `I ate an apple`:

- `I`: `主语`
- `ate`: `谓语`
- `an apple`: `宾语`

Comment: "an apple" is the 宾语 I think.

Comment: @wznmickey No, `an` is used to quantify the quantiy of `apple`, I think it is called `定语`.

Comment: @jdhao Surely the two words together serve as the object in the sentence, so "an apple" *is* 宾语.

Comment: @iBug I am not an expert on this topic, maybe you are right. Some references would be great :)

Comment: @jdhao Might as well check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)). It lists "the dog" in "She sees *the dog*" as the (direct) object in the sentence. In this example, "the dog" is a *noun phrase* that serves as the object in the *sentence*, and "the" is an article (定语) in the *noun phrase*. The scope is different.

Comment: Also, the terminology for 谓语 is *predicate*. In English we may say "SVO order", which is probably because a predicate is always a verb. There exists non-predicate verb (surely).

Answer (score 4):

This can be called `主谓宾` or `主动宾语序`:

> Subject–verb–object word order (主动宾语序) [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object_word_order)

> subject-verb-object SVO or subject-predicate-object sentence pattern (e.g. in Chinese grammar) [Source](https://www.omgchinese.com/dictionary/chinese/%E4%B8%BB%E8%B0%93%E5%AE%BE)